# RCurl handle Chinese characters

Tags: javascript, r, character-encoding, rcurl

This is my code. Why cannot it not decode Chinese characters correctly:

```
    library(XML)
    require(RCurl)
    myURL <- "http://data.eastmoney.com/zjlx/600066.html"
    html <- getURL(myURL,.encoding = "gb2312")
    print(Encoding(html))
    basicInfo <- htmlParse(html)
    #print(Encoding(basicInfo))
    tables <- readHTMLTable(basicInfo)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that website dynamically adds data to the tables with javascript. If you load the page in a browser with js disabled, you'll notice you don't see any data there either.

Answer (score 0):

I had some limited success on the javascript side of things but not the encoding (something is wrong with the character encoding when giving it over to R which I don't know how to correct):

```
# On Windows install the packages and required files
require(devtools)
install_github('seleniumJars', 'LluisRamon')
install_github('relenium', 'LluisRamon')

# Load package
require(relenium)

# Start a new instance of Firefox (this must already be installed on your computer)
firefox <- firefoxClass$new()

# We go to the url using the function get.
firefox$get("http://data.eastmoney.com/zjlx/600066.html")

# The html from the webpage can be obtained with the getPageSource (and returning a "character") function.
html <- firefox$getPageSource()

# Parse the html using the XML package
doc <- htmlParse(html)

# Extract your table
tables <- readHTMLTable(doc, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
mytable <- tables$dt_1

           V1    V2     V3          V4      V5           V6      V7          V8      V9         V10     V11          V12     V13
1  2014-07-24 18.30  2.81%  3893Ã¤Â¸Â‡  10.63%   -323Ã¤Â¸Â‡  -0.88%  4217Ã¤Â¸Â‡  11.52% -1600Ã¤Â¸Â‡  -4.37%  -2293Ã¤Â¸Â‡  -6.26%
2  2014-07-23 17.80 -0.50%  1287Ã¤Â¸Â‡   8.63%  27.48Ã¤Â¸Â‡   0.18%  1259Ã¤Â¸Â‡   8.44%  -333Ã¤Â¸Â‡  -2.24%   -953Ã¤Â¸Â‡  -6.39%
3  2014-07-22 17.89  4.25%  7765Ã¤Â¸Â‡  18.46%   5729Ã¤Â¸Â‡  13.62%  2036Ã¤Â¸Â‡   4.84% -4574Ã¤Â¸Â‡ -10.87%  -3190Ã¤Â¸Â‡  -7.58%
```

I don't know if the stringi package will help in this case. It may work under Linux (I often find that text encoding issues are far less in Linux than Windows but that is anecdotal).